# Only Z offset for BLTouch?

Tags: marlin, g-code, bltouch, creality-ender-5

I'm having a hard time getting my Ender 5 Plus (I'm using stock firmware 1.70.2 BL) trammed and in the pursue of that I decided to check my probe offset values. As it seems there is only a Z offset configured? Or does `M851` only show the Z value?

```
Send: M851
Recv: echo:Z Offset  zprobe_zoffset= -2.08
Recv: ok
```

Answer (score 1):

For Marlin 1.1.x, the Z-offset is shown with [`M851`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M851:_Set_Z-Probe_Offset).

For Marlin 2.0.x it is also possible to change the X and Y offset values through the [`M851` G-code](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M851.html) using `X` and `Y` (outside the default `Z`) parameter options. Without parameters, `M851` returns the following in a [terminal](/q/10573):

```
Send: M851
Recv:   M851 X0.00 Y55.00 Z0.00 ; (mm)
```

Considering [this from All3DP](https://all3dp.com/2/creality-ender-5-plus-firmware/):

> First up is the official Creality firmware, which is based on older versions of Marlin. Creality doesn’t mention which exact version of Marlin it’s based on, but it’s likely a variation of Marlin 1.9 that’s slightly changed to match Creality’s needs.

What is meant here is that Creality is secret about their use of which version of firmware they use, but it is most likely based on the 1.1.9 code base. If so, this implies that in your case, while running stock firmware, you should only see the Z-offset, not the X and Y offsets.

---

Digging even further, it appears that Creality has released the Ender 5 Plus firmware through their [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16596EvFWv9C9ClbavmHPc4J3MJ4_N3h_). When you look into the code, the firmware version is indeed from the 1.1.x branch, they reference to 2016/2017 Marlin development. If you look into the sources you will see that `M851` indeed only returns the Z-offset.